# Unsummable factorial power series in digital communication problems

Tags: probability, summation

I have encountered a problem in communication theory, well, not really into communication but mostly math. You can find the original problem at bottom, but I'll first explain what the problem I have.

To solve the problem I applied all the rules from theory and come up with the following equation.
$$
P_{\text{error}}=\left(1-P_{\text{off}}\right) e^{T \left(-\lambda _{\text{on}}\right)} \sum _{k=0}^{k_0} \frac{\left(T \lambda _{\text{on}}\right){}^k}{k!}+P_{\text{off}} e^{T \left(-\lambda _{\text{off}}\right)} \sum _{k=\text{k0}}^{\infty } \frac{\left(T \lambda _{\text{off}}\right){}^k}{k!}\\
\lambda _{\text{on}}>\lambda _{\text{off}}\geq 0
$$
The question asks you to minimize the probability error by choosing the $k_0$. I tried to solve it with $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$ but failed. Then I start to plot the graphs in Mathematica, but can't find any clue by tuning the parameters.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Poff*(Lambdaoff*T)^k/k!*
    E^(-Lambdaoff*T), (1 - Poff)*((Lambdaoff + offset)*T)^k/k!*
    E^(-(Lambdaoff + offset)*T)}, {k, 1, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> Full], {Poff, 0, 1}, {Lambdaoff, 0, 1}, {offset, 0, 
  10}, {T, 0, 10}]
```

The basic idea of the problem is there's a laser transmitter sending message one and message two, it uses laser intensity $\lambda = \lambda_{off}$ for message one and laser intensity $\lambda = \lambda_{on}$ for message two. According to these laser intensity $\lambda$, the received number of photons is Poisson distribution which means
$$
P_1 (k=k|M=1)=\frac{e^{T \left(-\lambda _{\text{off}}\right)} \left(T \lambda _{\text{off}}\right){}^k}{k!}\\P_2 (k=k|M=2)=\frac{e^{T \left(-\lambda _{\text{on}}\right)} \left(T \lambda _{\text{on}}\right){}^k}{k!}
$$
The question also states that the probability of sending message one or two is follow.
$$
P(M=1)=P_{\text{off}}\\P(M=2)=P_{\text{on}}\\0<P_{on}=1-P_{off}<1
$$
After I applied the Bayes rule, the probability of receiving $k$ photons and sending message one or two can be obtained.
$$
P_1(k=k,M=1)=\frac{P_{\text{off}} e^{T \left(-\lambda _{\text{off}}\right)} \left(T \lambda _{\text{off}}\right){}^k}{k!}\\P_2(k=k,M=2)=\frac{P_{\text{on}} e^{T \left(-\lambda _{\text{on}}\right)} \left(T \lambda _{\text{on}}\right){}^k}{k!}
$$
Let's say now we have a table of probabilities by evaluating these two equations. From $k=0$ to infinity.
$$
P(M=1,k=0)\ P(M=1,k=1)\ ...\ P(M=1,k=n) \\
P(M=2,k=0)\ P(M=2,k=1)\ ...\ P(M=2,k=n) 
$$

According to problem I need to find a $k_0$, if $k<k_0$, we decode the signal as message one otherwise we decode it as message two.

What I do here is first trying to compare the probability plot of k by using the Mathematica code above, but not really useful. Second I tried to calculate the error probability by summing the probability table ($k>k_0$ part of first row $k_0>k$ part of second row), but still no luck. I think there's some math techniques to do this summation trick, So I posted the question here.

I'm also wondering the question itself might be wrong because it's way beyond the topic of digital communication (at first beginner lecture).

Original Problem:

> Consider an optical communication system. A binary message is transmitted by switching the intensity $\lambda$ of a laser "on" or "off" within the time-interval $[0,T]$. For message $m=1$ ("off") the intensity $\lambda = \lambda_{\text{off}}\ge0$. For message $m=2$ ("on") the intensity $\lambda=\lambda_{\text{on}}>\lambda_{\text{off}}$.
>
> The laser produces photons that are counted by a detector. The number $K$ of photons is a non-negative random variable, and the corresponding probabilities are
> $$\mathrm{Pr}\{K=k\}=\frac{(\lambda T)^k}{k!}\mathrm{exp}(-\lambda T),\quad\text{for }k=0,1,2,\cdots.$$

> This probability distribution is known as Poisson distribution.
>
> The a-priori message probabilities are $\mathrm{Pr}\{M=1\}=p_{\text{off}}$ and $\mathrm{Pr}\{M=2\}=p_{\text{on}}$. It is assumed that $0<p_{\text{on}}=1-p_{\text{off}}<1$.
>
> The detector forms the message estimate $\hat{m}$ based on the number $k$ of photons that are counted.
>
> (a) Suppose that the detector chooses $\hat{m}$ such that the probability of error $P_\epsilon=\mathrm{Pr}\{\hat{M}\neq M\}$ is minimized. For what values of $k$ does the detector choose $\hat{m}=1$ and when does it choose $\hat{m}=2$?